# Saving modified data in gridview on clicking SaveButton

Tags: c#, winforms

I am strugglig doing a save button in C# Windows Form Application where I have a GridView and I want to save all modification I do in GridView Table(I connected it to sql). This is the data source for my database `DataTable dtCustomers = new DataTable();`

I did this so far and got stucked.

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                var isAnyRowUpdated = false;
                foreach (GridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    //detect modifications in GridView table
                    if (//condition to modify)
                    {
                        isAnyRowUpdated = true;
                        using (con)
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                            using (cmd)
                            {
                                cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET " +
                                          "CustomerId = @CustomerId, " +
                                          "FirstName = @FirstName, " +
                                          "LastName = @LastName, " +
                                          "Email = @Email, " +
                                          "Height = @Height, " +
                                          "DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth ";
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "StudentID");
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "FirstName");
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "LastName");
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1, "Email");
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Height", SqlDbType.Int, 50, "Height");
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.Date, 10, "DateOfBith");
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                                {
                                    da.UpdateCommand = cmd;
                                    // da.Update();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
               
                if (!isAnyRowUpdated)
                {
                    //alert no rows are updated
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

How to check the modified data and set condition to modify? (where are comments in code)

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: ok, I will do, thank you!

Comment: You can bind your DataGridView to a DataTable as a data source, and then each change would appear on the DataTable on modification.